# Recursive wget to stdout?

Tags: wget

I want to create a stream of the HTML found by continuously mirroring an entire website, as might be done in the following command:

```
wget -mqO- <site>
```

The m option specifies mirroring (recursive search), the q option is to disable progress bars, and O- should redirect to stdout. But this command stops after the output of the first page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed a workaround by writing all the output to a file instead:

```
wget -mqO <file> <site>
```

Which is, I suppose, neater. It seems to work fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The recursive switch is `-r`, use that.

Comment: -k or -r can be used together with -O only if outputting to a regular file. Will not work for writing to stdout.